# C++0x unique_ptr replaces scoped_ptr taking ownership?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, c++11

I used to write code like this:

```
class P {};

class Q: public P {};

class A {
    // takes ownership
    A(P* p): p_(p) {}

    scoped_ptr<P> p_;
};

A a(new Q);
```

With C++0x, should I rewrite class A as:

```
class A {
    // takes ownership
    A(unique_ptr<P>&& p): p_(p) {}

    unique_ptr<P> p_;
};
```

Comment: Similarly, is there a C++0x replacement for `boost::scoped_array`?

Comment: @rafak `std::unique_ptr` works with arrays as well (it will call delete[])

Comment: @rafak: use unique_ptr like this `std::unique_ptr<P[]>`.  Not only will unique_ptr call delete[] when it's deallocated, but it disables the * and -> operators instead it provides a [] operator.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I've upvoted comonad's answer, but with a caveat:

> Whenever you want to explicitely
>   ***disallow*** move semantics, use a **<del>scoped_ptr</del> const unique_ptr**.

I have not come across any use cases where a `const std::unique_ptr` is inferior to a `boost::scoped_ptr`.  However I'm open to education on the subject.

Edit:

Here is a use case of `boost::scoped_ptr` that I think should fail, but does not.  It does fail for `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef USE_UNIQUEPTR

#include <memory>
typedef std::unique_ptr<int> P;

#else  // USE_UNIQUEPTR

#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
typedef boost::scoped_ptr<int> P;

#endif  // USE_UNIQUEPTR

int main()
{
    P p1(new int(1));
    {
        // new scope
#ifdef USE_UNIQUEPTR
        const P p2(new int(2));
#else  // USE_UNIQUEPTR
        P p2(new int(2));
#endif  // USE_UNIQUEPTR
        swap(p1, p2);  // should fail!
    }
    std::cout << *p1 << '\n';
}
```

If the promise of `boost::scoped_ptr` is that its resource will not escape the current scope, then it is not as good at holding that promise as a `const std::unique_ptr`.  If we want to compare const boost::scoped_ptr to const::std::unique_ptr, I have to ask: for what purpose?  They seem the same to me, except that a const std::unique_ptr allows customized construction and destruction.

Comment: Nice trick! I did not think about using any const ptr. Actually, in some cases where I want to forbid copy and move semantics, I still want to use swap semantics. It is just that I do not want any null pointers – not even in race conditions. Without allowing swap semantics, would there be any difference between const scoped_ptr and const unique_ptr?

Comment: The only difference I can think of between const scoped_ptr and const unique_ptr is that the latter allows for a custom deallocator, and a custom pointer type.  If you want to use swap, but don't want move or copy, then scoped_ptr sounds like the best fit.  However scoped_ptr allows nulls as easily as unique_ptr.  You may want a smart pointer that hasn't been discussed yet (and I haven't seen): not_null_ptr.

Comment: a `scoped_ptr` can be reset to a different pointer. Does `const unique_ptr` allow that?

Comment: Nope.  A `const unique_ptr` says:  I'm holding this pointer from construction until destruction.

Answer (score 30):

- A **auto_ptr** is a pointer ***with*** *copy* and ***with*** *move* semantics and ownership (=auto-delete).
- A **unique_ptr** is a **auto_ptr** *without copy* but ***with*** *move* semantics.
- A **scoped_ptr** is a **auto_ptr** *without copy* and *without move* semantics.

  **auto_ptr**‍s are allways a ***bad choice*** – that is obvious.

  Whenever you want to explicitely ***have*** move semantics, use a **unique_ptr**.

  Whenever you want to explicitely ***disallow*** move semantics, use a **scoped_ptr**.
- All pointers allow **swap** semantics, like `p.swap(q)`. To disallow those, use any **const …_ptr**.

There are situations, where you want to use a **scoped_ptr** pointing to one of several interchangeable objects: Because of the absence of move semantics, it is quite safe (in respect to obvious bugs) that it will not accidentally point to null because of an unintended move. Worth to mention: **scoped_ptr**‍s can still be **swap**‍ped efficiently. To make it movable and/or copyable – but still with these swap semantics – you might want to consider using a **shared_ptr** pointing to a **scoped_ptr** pointing to an exchangeable (via scoped_ptr::swap) object.

See [stackoverflow:smart-pointers-boost-explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569775/) for further details.

Comment: I agree with you, and it looks like you agree with James' answer.  Thanks for taking the time to answer...

Answer (score 2):

IMO it is better to use `unique_ptr` as it provides an additional feature: **move semantics**. i.e. you can write a move constructor, etc for your class, unlike `scoped_ptr`. Also, `unique_ptr` doesn't have an overhead associated with it as it is the case with `scoped_ptr`, so it is a superior facility. A decision of a rewrite is up to you of course, in case you don't need move semantics then there is no point of the rewrite. Don't forget that `unique_ptr` is from the standard library, so it must be provided with any compliant implementation of C++0x(when it becomes reality of course :)!

Comment: `scoped_ptr` does not incur overhead. You're probably thinking of `shared_ptr` :)

Comment: @Billy ONeal Sometimes I don't know how to express something in English :) Basically, I wanted to say, both don't create overhead.

Comment: If they both don't create overhead, then why is one "superior" compared to the other? (Referencing -> "doesn't have an overhead associated with it as it is the case with scoped_ptr, so it is a **superior** facility")

Answer (score 2):

I have to disagree with AraK on one being superior.  There is no such thing as a superior choice between the two as it often depends on usage.  That's like saying a SmartCar is superior to a pick-up truck for all uses because it's lighter and faster.  In reality, sometimes you need a truck and sometimes you don't.  Your choice of pointer should be based on what you need.

The nice thing about scoped_ptr is it adds a level of safety.  By using scoped_ptr you are delcaring that the memory created will exist only for that scope and no more, thus you get compile-time protection against attempting to move it or transfer it.

So, if you want to create somethign but limit it's scope, used scoped_ptr.  If you want to create something and have ownership be movable, use unique_ptr.  If you want to create something and share that pointer and cleanup when all referencers are gone, use shared_ptr.

Comment: Sorry, but this is dead wrong. The biggest problem is that `unique_ptr` is in the standard, while `scoped_ptr` is not. Therefore, if a C++0x compiler is suitable for your application, you should always use `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Billy It might be better for someone with your experience to be extra kind with new members of our community who take the time to answer questions ;)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: my bad, you DO need to write `move(p)` inside the initialiser. `std::move` treats whatever it's given as an rvalue reference, and in your case, even though your argument is an rvalue reference to something, passing it to something else (like `p_`'s constructor) will pass an lvalue reference, never an rvalue reference by default.

Per Karu's comment, also added necessary includes to made my code compilable.

For example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class A {};

class B {
public:
  void takeOwnershipOf(unique_ptr<A>&& rhs) {
    // We need to explicitly cast rhs to an rvalue when passing it to push_back
    // (otherwise it would be passed as an lvalue by default, no matter what
    // qualifier it has in the argument list).  When we do that, the move
    // constructor of unique_ptr will take ownership of the pointed-to value
    // inside rhs, thus making rhs point to nothing.
    owned_objects.push_back(std::move(rhs));
  }

private:
  vector<unique_ptr<A>> owned_objects;
};

int main() {
  unique_ptr<B> b(new B());
  // we don't need to use std::move here, because the argument is an rvalue,
  // so it will automatically be transformed into an rvalue reference.
  b->takeOwnershipOf( unique_ptr<A>(new A()) );

  unique_ptr<A> a (new A());
  // a points to something
  assert(a);
  // however, here a is an lvalue (it can be assigned to). Thus we must use
  // std::move to convert a into an rvalue reference.
  b->takeOwnershipOf( std::move(a) );
  // whatever a pointed to has now been moved; a doesn't own it anymore, so
  // a points to 0.
  assert(!a);
  return 0;
}
```

Also, in your original example, you should rewrite class A like this:

class A {
    // takes ownership
    A(unique_ptr

&& p): p_(std::move(p)) {}

```
unique_ptr<P> p_;
```

};

Comment: @Dan: In your example, `owned_objects.push_back(rhs);` will not call the rvalue version of `push_back`. You still need to say `owned_objects.push_back(std::move(rhs));` for that to happen. `rhs` is an rvalue reference (ie. that is the type of the variable `rhs`), but the expression `rhs` yields an lvalue (ie. you could say `rhs = something;` or `&rhs;` etc.). It can be confusing, but when an rvalue reference variable is mentioned as an expression, the result is an lvalue.