# How to add char*/convert to std::vector<uint8_t[]>

Tags: c++

I have a `std::vector<uint8_t[1115]>` and I want to store a `char*` in it.
I don't understand how I have to cast the char* to fit it into the vector.
Maybe its stupid but I tried this:

```
char* myCharArray = new char[1115]; 
std::vector<uint8_t[1115]> myVector;
myVector.push_back(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(myCharArray));
```

I don't understand why this is not working. The error is as follows:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<unsigned char [1115]>::push_back(uint8_t*)’
```

Comment: Also clarify what "not working" means. Does it not compile, or crash, or cause weird output, or steal your Facebook friends?

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<unsigned char [1115]>::push_back(uint8_t*)’

Comment: You had actually given the appropriate information but it wasn't showing because you hadn't formatted your question correctly. Please place back-ticks around any inline code in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. A `vector`'s elements have to be copy constructible and assignable, but an array is not. That means that you can't legally have a `vector` of arrays. If you are using C++11 or later, you can use a `std::vector<std::array<uint8_t, 1115>>`. The `std::array` type is a copyable wrapper around an array.
2. `push_back` takes an object that it can insert into the vector simply by copying the object. You can't copy a `char*` (or any other point) to an array. However, if you follow my recommendation in (1), you can avoid the pointer entirely, and just make it `std::array<uint8_t, 1115> myCharArray;`.

If `std::array` is not available to you, you could use a `std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>>` and just make sure the inner vectors are the right size.

You might be interesting in looking at [why you probably won't need raw pointers or `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22146244/150634) in most of your C++.

Comment: Okay, I can't use c++11 so I guess I have to find another way? Thank you for your help

Comment: @telina A `std::vector<std::vector<uint8_t>>` should work fine for you.