# Is there a rule of thumb on using pointers or references as return types of functions in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, function-pointers

N00b alert first. I hate doing something when I do not understand the underlying logic in it. So, very recently I have started using C++, and I still try to grasp the concept of pointers and references. Also, their usage as return types of functions.

So [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146094/why-should-i-use-a-pointer-rather-than-the-object-itself) a good explanation about when, where and why pointers and references should be used is explained. Does the same explanation stand valid for them as return types of functions?

Comment: It depends very much on the situation and what the function is doing. In some case you *must* return a reference, and in other case you can't. And if you want to return a pointer or reference, you can't return a pointer/reference to something that will disappear (like for example a local non-static variable).

Comment: Perhaps the best rule is that "return by value" is the default, except for some operators which by default should return a reference (e.g. `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the same difference you have between references and pointers in general, they are two different things meant for different uses.
A pointer is literally the address of something in memory (and therefore what it points to can be changed), a reference might be implemented the same way under the hood (and often is) but it's meant to to obscure memory addressing without losing the economies of pointing to existing objects instead of copying them.

Pointers have features that relate to their notional proximity to memory (pointer arithmetic to literally walk over stored data for one) and can be used to ignore a lot of rules that would apply elsewhere, references aren't anywhere as malleable but offer more safety and relative constness guarantees.

I'm not a fan of rules of thumb for these things to be honest, especially with pointers given how lethal they can be in the wrong place or hands, but if you absoutely must: As a noob using references for as long as it's reasonable if you have the choice is probably a safer bet. Pointers become somewhat mandatory at beginner levels only when you want to have a single dynamic accessor to multiple items in memory, or in some polymorphism cases.

If you are bound to some API and therefore have things set for you in terms of what is passed around in what form then you most likely will want to stick to whatever is handed to you (pointers stay pointers and are returned as such and same for refs).

In general when I hear noob, function, and returning pointers in the same sentence I become concerned for that person's safety :) As stated before remember scoping in C++, something created inside a function will be destroyed once it returns, and while you might get compiler warnings or obvious errors in these cases with refs or plain copies, if you start performing pointer tricks that's when it goes horribly wrong and errors can trickle a long way away from where they originate. It's still possible to make a mess of things with references, but nowhere as easily by a very long shot IMO.

I would still encourage you to look into things and try to get a better understanding of various uses and some implementations by looking at code within your reach rather than trying to gather rules of thumb. There is so much over simplification and omission in my post it's not funny, but I can't seem to articulate a better one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.

By reference:
Return by reference values that you've passed into the function by reference. Note that you can't return by reference a local variable that you've created in the function and that will go out of scope once the function returns.

By address:
Return by address variables that you've passed into the function by address. Note that you can't return by address a local variable that you've created in the function and that will go out of scope once the program exits the function.

Think of returning as the other side of the coin from passing.