# Find pointer of object in vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class which is called `Position`:

```
class Position
{
    public:
    ... //Constructor, Destructor, ...

    private:

      signed int x_;
      signed int y_;
}
```

Then I have a vector which stores pointers of `Positions`:

```
std::vector<Position*> positions
```

How can I check if a `Position` is contained in the vector? For example, I have an object of a `Position`:

```
Position* p_ = new Position(0, 0);
```

And I want to check if the vector contains a `Position` with the same coordinates?
Which operator do I have to overload?

Thanks,
Barbara

Comment: Why are you storing pointers to positions instead of the positions themselves? Seems like a recipe for bugs.

Comment: Yeah I am also quite unsure about this. I asked one of my teammates why he does this and he said it would be more efficient and faster and it should not be changed - EVER.

Comment: Wow. I'm glad I'm not in this project.

Comment: "it would be more efficient and faster and it should not be changed" .. Yeah right. Because indirection is soooo efficient.

Comment: @user3347983 well you can stop listening to him then... Until he reads about cache optimization and locality of reference.

Comment: Sorry, I am totally a beginner in C++ and pointers.
Can you maybe explain to me why it is efficient / why not?

Comment: Read this question: [Why should I use a pointer rather than the object itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22146094/96780) and its answers.

Comment: I also recommend you to read some of the books recommended in this question: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/96780).

Comment: @user3347983 It's a whole topic. The gist of it is that the CPU uses (several levels of) cache to load whole chunks of data from RAM. When you store and access elements contiguously, you *hit* the cache : the object you access is already loaded in the previous chunk. However, by using pointers (to non-contiguous objects) you force the CPU to hop around in memory, *missing* the cache and reloading it for each object. Upshot : it gets **slow**.

Comment: Another reference is [this one](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/value-vs-ref-semantics#compos-vs-heap). Basically, you should learn and search for answers yourself, instead of believing the myths somebody else tells you.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Since it is the second day I use C++ and our professor didn't make any words about this topic, you may understand that I will not verify every single explanation someone gives to me.

Comment: @DanielDaranas I agree with you concerning the searching for the answers.  However, too many beginners really don't know that what they've been told is dubious at best, and nonsense at worst.  If the code compiles, then hey, it's "ok" to them until their program crashes or gives wrong results.

Comment: @Babs I gave recommendations according to the contents of your question. You may follow them or not, according to your free will.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm just giving recommendations that I find useful for a beginner to actually _learn_ how to code in C++. I'm not actually in charge of his team. If I was, I'd make sure they learn.

Answer (score 5):

```
auto it = find_if(positions.begin(), positions.end(), 
                 [=](position* p)
                 {
                    return p->x() == p_->x() && p->y() == p_->y();
                 });

if(it != positions.end())
{
       //object found
}
```

However, unless you have a real reason to store pointers in the vector (e.g. you're going to use polymorphism), storing objects directly is much simpler.

```
vector<position> v;
v.push_back(Position(1, 2));
...
Position p_(1, 4);
auto it = find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), 
                  [=](position p)
                  {
                      return p.x() == p_.x() && p.y() == p_.y();  
                  });
if(it != v.end())
{
   //position found
}
```

In the latter case it is possible to further simplify the code by overloading operator == for position.

```
bool operator == (position p1, position p2)
{
   return p1.x == p2.x && p1.y == p2.y; //assuming operator == is declared friend
}
```

Then you can

```
auto it = find(v.begin(), v.end(), p_);
```

Comment: Thanks :)
@BillLynch I've worked with operator overloading :)

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan I would highly suggest using `const&` on the second example... no need to create a copy of the object when a reference will do.

Comment: @Mgetz: the object is simply two ints, I think its copy is cheaper than reference creating.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to class Position

```
Public:
bool isSamePosition(position * p){
    return p->x == this->x && p->y ==this->y;
}
```

Then compare with all in the vector

```
bool unique = true;
for (int i = 0; i < positions.length(); ++i){
    if (new_position->isSamePosition(positions[i])
        unique = false;
}
if (unique==true)
 //do something like push_back vector
;
```

Comment: Why not use `operator==`?

Comment: Yup, probably best as long as there aren't or won't be any other comparable members in Position

Answer (score 0):

> And I want to check if the vector contains a Position with the same coordinates? Which operator do I have to overload?

If you had a vector of positions (instead of vector of pointers to positions) the operator you'd have to overload would be:

```
bool Position::operator==(const Position& p);
```

With this code, you could write (assuming you are using `std::vector<Position> positions;`, and not `std::vector<Position*> positions;`):

```
using std::find; using std::begin; using std::end;
const Position p{}; // element that is sought after
bool exists = (end(positions) != find(begin(positions), end(positions), p));
```

> [comment:] Yeah I am also quite unsure about this. I asked one of my teammates why he does this [i.e. store by pointers] and he said it would be more efficient and faster and it should not be changed - EVER.

It is probably not more efficient, nor faster than storing by values. If you are not in a position to change the vector though, you will have to add the operator declared above, and also a predicate that compares a Position instance to the values in a Position pointer, and using that with std::find:

```
    const Position p{}; // element that is sought after
    auto matches_position = [&p](Position const* const x)
    {
        return x != nullptr // can positions in the vector be null?
            && p == *x;
    };

    bool exists = (end(positions) != find(begin(positions), end(positions),
        matches_position));
```

== Coping strategy ==

I would go for the first version (no pointers in the vector), by doing the following:

1. create a new (minimalistic) project, that fills two separate vectors, with a bunch of randomized positions (fixed number of positions, between 2000 and 10000 instances or so); the vectors should contain positions by pointer and by value respectively, with the same values in each position (a position should be in both vectors, at the same index)
2. perform the search for the same values in both vectors.
3. repeat the searches multiple times (to average and minimize timing errors)
4. take results to your colleague(s).

There are two outcomes from this: either your colleague is right (which seems pretty unlikely, but *hey! who knows?*) or he is wrong, and his code that "should never be changed" - well ... it should be changed.

Comment: we discussed for an hour now and now i am totally allowed to change the vector :D