# Cannot convert parameter 1 from Person to Person *[]

Tags: c++, file, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm trying to make program that reads from a file and adds to a binary tree, but when I try to compile I get an error:

> "Error    1   'treePersons::display' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Node *' to 'Person *[]'"

The error appears in the call to `display()` in `main()`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Person{
  int social;
  int birthday;
  string first;
  string last;
  string state;
  double balance;
  Person();
  Person(int s, int b, string f, string l, string t, double a)
  {
    social = s;
    birthday = b;
    first = f;
    last = l;
    state = t;
    balance = a;
}
};

struct Node{
    Person data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    Node();
    Node(Person x){
        data = x;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
};

class treePersons
{
protected:

public:
    Node *root;
    treePersons(){
        root = NULL;
}

int fileName(Person *data[])
{
  ifstream fin; 
  fin.open ("dbfile1.txt");  
  if (!fin.is_open())
      cout << "File not found" << endl;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i<100; i++)
      while(fin.good())
      {
          fin >> data[i]->social >> data[i]->birthday >> data[i]->first >> data[i]->last >> data[i]->state >> data[i]->balance;
          i++;
      }
      return i;
}
void add(Person *data[], Node*root)
{
    int i = fileName(data);
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = new Node();
    }
    for(int l = 0; l<i; l++)
    {
    if(data[i]->last == root->data.last)
    {
        if(data[i]->first != root->data.first)
        {
          if(data[i]->first < root->data.first)
          {
            add(data, root->left);
          }
          else if(data[i]->first > root->data.first)
          {
            add(data, root->right);
          }
          else if(data[i]->last == root->data.last && data[i]->first == root     ->data.first)
          {
            cout << "already exists" << endl;
          }
          else if(data[i]->first < root->data.first)
          {
            add(data, root->left);
          }
          else if(data[i]->first > root->data.first)
          {
            add(data, root->right);
          }
        }
    }
    }
}

void printAlphabetically(Node *root)
{
  if (root != NULL) 
  {
    printAlphabetically(root->left);
    cout << root->data.last << endl;
    printAlphabetically(root->right);
  }
return;
}

void display(Person *data[],Node *root)
{
    add(data,root);
    printAlphabetically(root);
};

};

struct State{
    string state;
    Person data;
    State* left;
    State * right;
    State();
    State(Person x)
    {
        data = x;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }


};

class treeState{
protected:
    State *root;
public:
    treeState()
    {
        root = NULL;
    }
};

void main(){
    treePersons T;
    T.display(T.root->data,T.root);
}
```

Comment: There too many problems in your code. My suggstion: work through some tutorials on the web or exercises in a text book. As far as the posted program is concerned, I suggest start small, make sure it works, and then keep adding more code.

Comment: Can you point out what needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple to see what's wrong with your code. You have the following:

```
treePersons T;
T.display(T.root->data, T.root);
```

Let's have a look at what a `treePersons` is:

```
class treePersons
{
    Node *root;
    ...
};
```

It contains a single member: a `Node`. A `Node` is:

```
struct Node
{
    Person data;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    ...
};
```

Your `treePersons::display()` function has the following signature:

```
void display(Person *data[], Node *root)
```

And you are passing a `t.root->data` (a `Person`) and `t.root` (a `Node*`)

The problem is you are attempting to pass a `Person` as a `Person*[]` which just isn't going to happen. There's no way to make that `Person` into a `Person[]`, and you probably meant to make `display` take a `Person*` pointer, which will allow you pass a single `Person` or a container of `Person`: `void display(Person* data, Node* root);`

Of course, doing so will lead you down a big trail of problems as @R Sahu pointed out in the comments (most of your functions take a `Person*[]`. The solution here is to rethink what you are doing, and as @R Sahu suggests start **much** smaller and build up your program from there.

Consider also using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) when you need containers, and [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) where you **require** pointers (otherwise [just use objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146094/why-should-i-use-a-pointer-rather-than-the-object-itself)!). Also read (really **read**) the compiler output. It's telling you what the problem is, you just need to **read**.