# When to Sink a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I'm relatively new to C++ and want to adopt modern practice. I've been trying to understand when it's best to [sink](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-91-smart-pointer-parameters/) a `unique_ptr`, here is some code I have:

```
class SomeClass
{
    ...

private:
    unique_ptr<QStaticText> _text;
}


{
    ...

    void SomeClass::setText(unique_ptr<QStaticText> newText)
    {
        _text = move(newText);
    }

    void SomeClass::setText(const QStaticText& newText)
    {
        _text = make_unique<QStaticText>(newText);
    }

    ...
}
```

Should I prefer one over the other, either or another?

Comment: The second one should be preferred. But it's a bit unclear why you can't have a `QStaticText` member directly.

Comment: Your example sucks, but the general idea is that you accept or return a `unique_ptr` when you want to transfer ownership. This is especially important when the resource being transferred can't be copied (uncopyable, expensive, full type unknown), which is also what makes your example so bad. If you can copy and assign a `QStaticText`, don't use pointers. In general, avoid using `new`, although it might be slightly different with Qt.

Comment: Have a read of Herb Sutter: Smart Pointer Parameters: http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the interface of [`QStaticText`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstatictext.html), it's unclear why you're using pointers (smart or otherwise) at all. (I believe panta rei noted this in a comment too.) Have a look at [Why Should I Use a Pointer Rather Than the Object Itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146094/why-should-i-use-a-pointer-rather-than-the-object-itself).

In this case, it might be better to have something like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    ...

private:
    QStaticText _text;
};


template<class Text>
void SomeClass::setText(const Text &newText)
{
    _text = QStaticText(newText);
}
```

Note the following:

1. `QStaticText` is just optimized for infrequent changes.
2. It is constructible by at least two different types.

It's hard to see what you gain by your present scheme. For each update, you're creating multiple objects anyway, and you can't reuse them (you're moving the content out of them).

Comment: Great, so a different approach would be: class SomeClass
{
    ...

private:
    QString _text;
}


{
    ...
    
    void SomeClass::setText(const QString& newText)
    {
        _text = QStaticText(newText);
    }

    ...
}

Comment: @PeterSpencer Yes; what I wrote is a slight generalization of that, as it can take either a `QString` or a `QStaticText`. As far as your original q. goes, though - I think your current suggestion is better than the original one.