# Baseclass method is called instead of the one in the subclass

Tags: c++

I've created a `BaseClass` and two subclasses: `SubOne` and `SubTwo`. After that I created a collection called `MyCollection` which stores the instances in a vector.

Both the base class, and the subclasses have the method `getString`. Base class returns with `base`, and the subclasses with `sub1` and `sub2`.

I don't get any warning or error during the compilation. But for some reason, if I try to iterate over the vector, the subclasses return "base"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class BaseClass {

    public:

        BaseClass() {}

        std::string getString() {
            return "base";
        }

};

class SubOne : public BaseClass {

    public:

        SubOne() : BaseClass() {}

        std::string getString() {
            return "sub1";
        }

};

class SubTwo : public BaseClass {

    public:

        SubTwo() : BaseClass() {}

        std::string getString() {
            return "sub2";
        }

};

class MyCollection {

    private:

        std::vector<BaseClass> instances;

    public:

        MyCollection() {}


        void add(BaseClass & ins) {
            instances.push_back(ins);
        }

        std::string printString() {

            for(std::vector<BaseClass>::iterator it = instances.begin() ; it != instances.end(); ++it) {
                std::cout << it->getString() << std::endl;
            }

        }

};

int main() {

    MyCollection *coll = new MyCollection();

    SubOne* s1 = new SubOne();
    SubTwo* s2 = new SubTwo();

    coll->add(*s1);
    coll->add(*s2);

    coll->printString();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is object slicing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Your function isn't virtual. And more importantly your vector is of `BaseClass`, not `BaseClass &`.so you're slicing.

Comment: it is not a duplicate

Comment: Are you coming from Java or C#?

Comment: @IterAtor You just don't know what slicing is so you don't know that it is.

Comment: Yes, I'm coming from java

Comment: It's painfully obvious. C++ is nothing like java inspite of superficial similarity. [Get a good C++ book]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1) and learn C++.

Comment: This will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146094/why-should-i-use-a-pointer-rather-than-the-object-itself

Comment: I can't really learn from books. I can learn from coding, and my mistakes. 

Could you please give me some hints, how to create a collection like this?

Comment: Take the time to learn to learn from books. You're going to waste a lot of time otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use keyword `virtual`. Also translate to pointers (credit goes to Captain Giraffe).

See code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class BaseClass {

public:

    BaseClass() {}

    virtual std::string getString() { // BINGO _!_!_!_!
        return "base";
    }

};

class SubOne : public BaseClass {

public:

    SubOne() : BaseClass() {}

    std::string getString() {
        return "sub1";
    }

};

class SubTwo : public BaseClass {

public:

    SubTwo() : BaseClass() {}

    std::string getString() {
        return "sub2";
    }

};

class MyCollection {

private:

    std::vector<BaseClass*> instances;

public:

    MyCollection() {}


    void add(BaseClass* ins) {
        instances.push_back(ins);
    }

    std::string printString() {

        for(std::vector<BaseClass*>::iterator it = instances.begin() ; it != instances.end(); ++it) {
            std::cout << (*it)->getString() << std::endl;
        }

    }

};

int main() {

MyCollection *coll = new MyCollection();

SubOne* s1 = new SubOne();
SubTwo* s2 = new SubTwo();

coll->add(s1);
coll->add(s2);

coll->printString();

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You missed this: `std::vector<BaseClass> instances;` He's slicing.

Comment: the BaseClass can also be instantiated, that is why the `getString` is not virtual

Comment: @IterAtor That is an invalid argument. There is a big difference between pure virtual and virtual.

Comment: @rbaghbanli Not fixed. std::vector copies the values into its own container.

Comment: This is still not a good suggestion for OP. A good answer would replace the Java way with respectable c++ manners. This is, I concede, a tall order.

Comment: I don't want to ask you to fix my code. I just want to know, how to implement something like this in C++

Comment: In this version you need to `delete s1; delete d2; delete coll;` before `return 0;` in main