# Function does not return what is suppossed to return- c++

Tags: c++, function, dynamic, return

I am dealing with a problem, that has to do with dynamic allocation, in c++. I have the following function to calculate the rms of a signal

```
void FindRMS(int points, double* signal_x, double* signal_y, int presamples, double* mean, double* rms)
{       
    //double fraction_presamples_RMS = 0.9; // fraction of presamples to calculate RMS
  //Safety condition
  if (presamples>points) {
    printf("\nERROR: Too many presamples!\n\n");
    return;
  }

  //Main procedure
  (*rms)  =0.;  
  (*mean) =0.;

  for (int i=0; i<presamples; i++) {
    (*mean)+=signal_y[i];
    (*rms)+=pow(signal_y[i],2);
  }

  (*mean)/=presamples;
  (*rms)=sqrt((*rms)/presamples-pow((*mean),2));
    cout << "RMS was found to be : " << (*rms) << endl;

}
```

First of all, if I understand correctly, `double* <var>` means that the argument is expected to be dynamically defined, which means that its size will be limited by the hardware.

Then what I do, is to call this function in my code. A sample code is the following

```
void Analyze(unsigned int first_run, unsigned int last_run, unsigned int last-segment){

    int points = 9e6;//hSignal->GetNbinsX();
//double x[points], y[points], derivative[points]; // SIZE limited by COMPILER to the size of the stack frame
    double* x          = new double[points];           // SIZE limited only by OS/Hardware
    double* y          = new double[points];
    double* derivative = new double[points];
    double* mean       = new double[points];
    double* rms        = new double[points];
    for (int i = 0; i < points; i++){
        x[i] = hSignal->GetBinLowEdge(i+1);
        y[i] = hSignal->GetBinContent(i+1);
        //cout << " Bin Center " << hSignal->GetBinLowEdge(2) << endl;
    }
    FindRMS(points, x, y, 0.9*points, mean, rms);
    delete[] x;
    delete[] y;
    delete[] mean;
    cout << "The value of rms[10] = " << rms[10] << endl;

}
```

The weird thing is that when the program is executed I get a cout from the function with a logical rms, while before the program end I get that rms is 0.

Any idea or advice on why this is happening? The thing is that I have to stick with the function as is, because it belongs to a library I have to stick with...

I thought of changing the function to return a `double*` instead of `void` but nothing changed really... Here is the modified function

```
double* FindRMS(int points, double* signal_x, double* signal_y, int presamples, double* mean, double* rms)
{       
    //double fraction_presamples_RMS = 0.9; // fraction of presamples to calculate RMS
  //Safety condition
  if (presamples>points) {
    printf("\nERROR: Too many presamples!\n\n");
    //return;
  }

  //Main procedure
  (*rms)  =0.;  
  (*mean) =0.;

  for (int i=0; i<presamples; i++) {
    (*mean)+=signal_y[i];
    (*rms)+=pow(signal_y[i],2);
  }

  (*mean)/=presamples;
  (*rms)=sqrt((*rms)/presamples-pow((*mean),2));
    cout << "RMS was found to be : " << (*rms) << endl;

    return rms;

}
```

Comment: The return only matters if you are calling the function and assigning the result of the function to something else. If you just want it to print something `void` is fine.

Comment: *"First of all, if I understand correctly, double* means that the argument is expected to be dynamically defined"* No, it only means the parameter is a pointer. It doesn't say anything about what it points to. But you should probably be returning the mean and rms, not setting some variables from pointers.

Comment: @EliSadoff Thanks for your comment! In fact I don't want just to print the output. I want to use the output for later calculations!

Comment: @Thanos then you certainly want the method to return `double *`. Having said that, returning pointers is not always the cleanest thing in the world.

Comment: @EliSadoff I can understand that returning a pointer is weird, but what choice do I have? Since I am novice, I don't know how to get around this... But even if I change the function to `double*` I still get `0` for the rms

Comment: @juanchopanza I am confused... This definition `double* x          = new double[points];` is a dynamic one, right? Or is it the definition of a pointer?

Comment: Not really an answer, but why are you using dynamic allocation? I don't see anything here that requires it, and you might see a performance gain by not having to perform repeated dereferences.

Comment: Holy pointers, batman!

Comment: @JimV Thanks for your comment! First of all I was declaring the arrays like this `double x[points], y[points], derivative[points];`. Even though I didn't have any compilation errors, when I was executing my program, it was crashing. I thought that since my arrays have 9millions elements each, the stack wasn't enough. So by dynamically allocating my arrays, my program run.

Comment: When you do e.g. `double* x = new double[...]` you are both *defining* the pointer  variable `x` and *initializing* it. You initialize the variable to the value returned by the expression `new double[...]`. The expression `new double[...]` allocates memory dynamically. So in one statement you are both defining a variable, initializing it, and dynamically allocating memory.

Comment: @Thanos In that case, I'd use a pre-sized `vector` or `array` and let the container do the memory management for you: `std::vector<double> x(points, 0);`.

Comment: @JimV tha thing is that I don't know the size a'priori. So what do I do in this case?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I thought I was dynamically allocating by using `*`... Novice... Thanks a lot for that!!!

Comment: Isn't "points" the size that you'll need?

Comment: Here's a good write-up on when to use/avoid dynamic allocation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22146244/2924233

Comment: @JimV Yes... You are absolutely right! Sorry!

Comment: I don't think Stallman will approve of software designed to find him.

Answer (score 3):

In the function `FindRMS` you only set `*rms` which is the same as `rms[0]`. All other values in the array are uninitialized, which means their values will be *indeterminate* (and will seem to be random). Reading those uninitialized values will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am confused on the following : The function accepts also a `double* singal_x` and a `double* signal_y`. As far as I understand these are again `x[0]` and `y[0]`. But inside the function there is a loop over the `y[]` array!

Comment: @Thanos: The pointer `signal_y` points to the start of the array `y`.

Comment: @Thanos There is a difference between *declaring* a pointer and *dereferencing* a pointer. In C++ many operators and special characters can mean different things in different situation.

Comment: @Thanos Also to explain why *dereferencing* the pointer `rms` (i.e. using `*rms` in an expression) is the same as `rms[0]`, it's because for any pointer (let say `rms`) and index `i` the expressions `rms[i]` and `*(rms + i)` are the same.  That means `rms[0]` is the same as `*(rms + 0)` and since adding zero to something is a useless operation it can be removed which means `rms[0]` is the same as `*(rms)` which is the same as `*rms`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I get that! What I don't get is how this line `(*rms)+=pow(signal_y[i],2);` is valid in the sense that since the argument is only `signal_y[0]`(because it has been declared as `double* signal_y`), how does the function know any element in the `signal_y[]` array?

Comment: @Thanos You misunderstand the asterisk... In a declaration like when you declare the argument it means "this variable is a pointer", it doesn't mean anything else, it's not the dereference operator, so it doesn't mean `signal_y[0]` in the declaration. It only means `signal_y[0]` if you use the dereference operator in an expression. Like I said, the asterisk means different things depending on situation. In one place it means "declare as a pointer" and in another it means "dereference the pointer". Two different things, in two different situations.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I see what you mean... The function expects a pointer as an argument, therefore it has to be declared as such, so as to use the function. What I don't get is how to parse in the function the array? Is it valid to declare an array of pointers, like I am doing? And if I use as an argument `x` that has been declared as an array of pointers, will the function perform calculations with only the first element `x[0]`