# How to initialize long type pointer variable in c

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to initialize long type pointer variable like

```
long *status =1L;
```

it is giving me error that- value of type `long` cannot be used to initialize an entity of type `long*` .  please help me .
Thank you .

Comment: Why do you want pointer in the first place? And what do you want with that pointer?

Comment: That's because you're trying to assign `1` to a pointer which stores an address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I use a pointer rather than the object itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146094/why-should-i-use-a-pointer-rather-than-the-object-itself)

Comment: @Colin__s - A pointer holds an address, it isn't an address itself.

Comment: Are you in an embedded setting, and need to point to a specific address that you know by value? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Gcc compiler give me warning.

Comment: @rsp - Then compile with `-Werror`, your code will be better for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Acess to any normal variable can be :-*
**1**. By use of name of variable.
**2**. By use of address of variable.
**Note:- it's like you can find a person by using his/her name or by using his/her address in the society.**

**Ques**. What is Pointer variable?  Is it diffrent from normal variable we use to?
**Ans.**  A pointer is a  "special" variable which contains(*point to/refer to*) the address in memory of another variable.

**point 1.** We can have a pointer to any variable type.
**point 2**. It's used to **indirect access of variable**.
**point 3.** its key note to remember. Type of pointer defines the type of variable to which it can point(refer) to.

**Now, coming to you problem:-
you want to store a long value i.e. 1L  in a pointer variable .
which is totally wrong according the "use of pointer".**

Concept of Pointer-->

Whenever a variable is declared, system will allocate a location to that variable in the memory, to hold value. This location will have its own address number.

Let us assume that system has allocated memory location 80F for a variable a.

```
int a = 10 ;
```

[image]

We can access the value 10 by either using the variable name a or the address 80F. Since the memory addresses are simply numbers they can be assigned to some other variable. The variable that holds memory address are called pointer variables. A pointer variable is therefore nothing but a variable that contains an address, which is a location of another variable. Value of pointer variable will be stored in another memory location.

[image]

Comment: If you like the way of mine to solve you problem in efficient way, then you may do vote or accept the answer.. :)   otherwise, share you opinion or anything another doubt. ;)

Comment: it's ok dude.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning value `1L` to an address. Change it to :

```
long x = 1L;
long *status = &x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Pointer variable is used store some memory address. What you are trying to do here is store some value in a pointer(which is wrong). `1L` is a value of type `long` which your are trying to store in a pointer of type `long*`(this is what the error says). The correct way to do this is :

First, store the value in the memory:

```
long lg = 1L;
```

Second, initialize a pointer pointing to the memory location of above variable:

```
long* lptr = &lg; //&lg means address of the variable lg
```

To access the value `1L` you can chose any of the following methods:

```
printf("%ld",lg);
```

OR

```
printf("%ld",*lptr);
```

Output of both the printf will be the same

Comment: "*memory address(integers)*" a memory address does not necessarily need to be one integer.

Comment: @alk Yes you are right . _"memory address(integers)"_ could be misleading.