# Why use `bool** adjacencyMatrix;` when dynamically allocating an array of pointers like this?: `adjacencyMatrix = new bool*[vertexCount];`

Tags: c++, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation, adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to understand an example of a graph represented by an adjacency matrix. I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
private:
      bool** adjacencyMatrix;
      int vertexCount;
public:
      Graph(int vertexCount) {
            this->vertexCount = vertexCount;
            adjacencyMatrix = new bool*[vertexCount];

            for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++) {
               adjacencyMatrix[i] = new bool[vertexCount];

                  for (int j = 0; j < vertexCount; j++)
                        adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = false;
            }
      }
```

I understand that `adjacencyMatrix` now points to an array of pointers to bool, But I can't understand why there are two `**` in the declaration of `adjacencyMatrix`.

I know I'm missing something very rudimentary but I just can't understand it. I've searched the Internet and couldn't find anything.

I just came here because there are so many knowledgeable and helpful people!

Comment: Look at this like It is an array of arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I use a pointer rather than the object itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146094/why-should-i-use-a-pointer-rather-than-the-object-itself)

Comment: Just like you said, it points to pointers.  Therefore, it is a double pointer.

Comment: I don't know why anyone would do it like that.  It would be much better to use `vector<vector<char>>`.  (`char` rather than `bool` because `vector<bool>` is optimized for space at the expense of speed).