# How to initialize member variable with super class type depending on constructor argument?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, member

After searching for hours, I end up here. I have a Container class with a pointer to Base class as member variable. This should either refer to Spec1 or another inherited classes of Base, which I omitted here. The type should be determined by the argument in constructor (e.g. string, enum, int, etc.).

I read much about dynamic memory allocation and why it should be avoided whenever possible. Is it possible to avoid here? Isnt any usual object destroyed after the constructor? Or is the design idea completely wrong? I come from Java :( Thanks in advance.

```
class Base{
  public:
    virtual ~Base(){}; // required?
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class Spec1 : public Base {
     public:
       Spec1(){};
       Spec1(int i){
         // whatever
       }
       void doSomething(){
          std::printf("hello world");
       }
};

class Container{
   public:
     Container(String type_message){
      if (type_message.compare("We need Spec1")){
          m_type = new Spec1(1);
      } // add more ifs for other types (Spec2, Spec3 etc.)
     }
     void doSomethingWithSpec(){
        m_type->doSomething();
     }
   private:
      Base* m_type;
 };

int main (int argc, char **argv){
    Container a ("We need Spec1");
    a.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: It is recommended to use `std::unique_ptr` and `std::make_unique` in your case, instead of raw pointers and `new`.

Comment: Your design is fine in general, though `Container` is missing a destructor to call `delete m_type;` (and should also disable the default copy constructor and copy assignment operator, since `m_type` should not be copied as-is). And yes, `~Base` needs to be `virtual`, so `delete m_type;` will work correctly, calling the destructor of whatever derived type you choose to instantiate.

Comment: Is the destructor called if the program is aborted by ctrl-c (ubuntu terminal)? Or do I have to call the destructor manually?

Comment: Regarding dynamic allocation being 'avoided whenever possible', this is true but if you want polymorphism in C++ then you *must* use pointers or references, so in cases like this (i.e. where a reference isn't suitable) you'll need to use dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Requiring `Container` to be aware of every possible derived class of `Base` does not sound like good design. That is what factory functions are for.

Have `Container` store that object as `std::unique_ptr` to avoid memory leaks and manual memory management.

```
struct Base {
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

struct Spec1 : Base {
    void doSomething() override {
        std::printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    }
};

// Factory function.
std::unique_ptr<Base> createBase(std::string const& type) {
    if(type == "Spec1")
        return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Spec1);
    throw std::runtime_error("Unknown type " + type);
}

class Container {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> m_type;
public:
    Container(std::string const& type)
        : m_type(createBase(type))
    {}

    void doSomething(){
        m_type->doSomething();
    }
};

int main() {
    Container a ("Spec1");
    a.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for factory function, didnt know before. But actually I want to keep it short and simple, and I do other stuff in constructor before, so that would be all passed to createBase method.

Comment: @Lucker10 `Container` and `Base` look like [strategy design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Constructor works like any other function. Local variables are allocated in stack and get out of scope whenever the function completes whereas dynamic memory allocation is done in stack and needs to be explicitaly deallocated (in C++ and not in Java) before the function completes.

However in your case

```
m_type = new Spec1(1);
```

`new Spec1(1)` is dynamically allocated in heap and won't get destroyed on completion of Constructor code. The reference is stored in the member variable of the class. So as long as the instance of class `Container` is in scope, the memory allocated to `Spec1(1)` can be referred.

To compare just consider other scenario.

```
Container(String type_message){
      Base* m_type;
      if (type_message.compare("We need Spec1")){
          m_type = new Spec1(1);
      } // add more ifs for other types (Spec2, Spec3 etc.)
     }
```

Here as soon as constructor finishes, `m_type` will go out of scope but `new Spec1(1)` will still be there in heap as the memory leak.

Comment: So there is no possibility to avoid the use of "new" ? Is this a typical use case for "new" ?

Comment: new here is similar to new in Java. You can avoid new by not declaring Base class object as pointer.
`Base m_type;
m_type = Spec1(1)`
You should avoid dynamic allocation as much as possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146094/why-should-i-use-a-pointer-rather-than-the-object-itself is a good read

Comment: That does not work for virtual class: `error: cannot declare field ‘Container::m_type’ to be of abstract type ‘Base’
         Base m_type;`