# dereference on new object when initiating new object

Tags: c++

I have some code where this is represented (I'm new to C++)

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
```

Would it give much sense to put the `*` here since `TessBaseAPI` is a new instance anyway?

`*api` means the "value of" right? (not the reference)

Comment: You need to [read a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). This is very basic C++ stuff, and you _cannot_ use the language without knowing this.

Comment: `T *a = b;` actually means `T *a; a = b;`, NOT `T *a; *a = b;`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I use a pointer rather than the object itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146094/why-should-i-use-a-pointer-rather-than-the-object-itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but it does not mean dereference in this case. I'll break up this line of code - `tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI()`.

For the left hand side, how I've learnt to read is to start from the identifier and go right and when you reach the end, go back left. So we start at `api` then go right but there's nothing (assuming we are only looking at the left hand side), so we head left. We see `*` and this means a pointer. Next we see `tesseract::TessBaseAPI`, which is the type of the pointer. Therefore, in words, **api is a pointer to tesseract::TessBaseAPI**. There are exceptions to this way of reading i.e. when there's brackets or array but that's the general idea.

For the right hand side, `new` means to allocate memory in the heap (as opposed to the compiler automatically allocating and deallocating memory for you in the stack) and thus, `new tesseract::TessBaseAPI()` means that you want to allocate enough memory in the heap for `tesseract::TessBaseAPI` object.

By combining the left and right hand sides, we get, in words, **api is a pointer of type tesseract::TessBaseAPI that is currently pointing to the memory location that has been allocated in the heap.**

If you're confused whether `*` means a pointer or dereference, it's a pointer when it's a *variable declaration or definition* and dereference otherwise. This means that after your line `tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI()`, whenever you call `*api`, it's a dereference.

**Edit:**

Allocating memory on the heap means you're responsible for it and the compiler will not help you to deallocate memory when you don't need it anymore. The method to deallocate memory is by calling `delete`. If you don't, you'll get *memory leak*.

There is another method to allocate memory, which is `malloc` and the method to deallocate is by calling `free`. The difference between `malloc` and `new` is that `malloc` just allocates memory whereas `new` allocates memory **and** calls the constructor. **DO NOT** deallocate memory by calling `free` that you've allocated by using `new` and vice versa. If you use `new`, only use `delete` and if you use `malloc`, only use `free`.

If you think manually allocating/deallocating memory is troublesome, C++11 introduced something called *smart pointers*, which automatically allocates and deallocates memory for you. So for example, instead of the line `tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI()`, you can have

`#include memory
auto ptr = std::make_unique<tesseract::TessBaseAPI>(); //ptr acts like a normal pointer`

When you don't need it anymore, just leave it as it is and it'll be deallocated when it exits its *scope*. This is a pretty neat way since there's no explicit `new` and `delete` so you don't have to worry about memory leak. Of course, there's some extra overhead as compared to using raw pointers so it's a trade-off.

Comment: Also, don't forget to mention `delete`!  Or at the very least, `std::unique_ptr`.