# Why do we really need pointers in Programming specifically C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, allocation

I can't really understand the difference between Dynamic and static allocation,they say Dynamic allocation happens while executing the program and static only while compiling and we can't allocate manually while execution but,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   int size , a = 0;

   cout << "Enter the size of Array: ";
   cin >> size;

   int A[size][size];
   for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
   {
        for(int j = 0 ; j < size ; j++)
            cout << a++ << '\t';
        cout << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This program will allocate the Array size while execution.

Comment: This is not valid C++, standard doesn't allow Variable Length Arrays. And stack is little compared to heap, you can't put huge objects on stack.

Comment: `int A[size][size];` is not legal C++, it is legal C. In any case dynamic memory allocation is about a lot more than array sizes. It's really about the **lifetime** of the object allocated. Dynamically allocated objects live until you deallocate them, that's not true with non-dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: you dont need pointers for dynamic arrays in C++, thats a myth coming from the C legacy. Use `std::vector` if you need a dynamic array

Comment: And, furthermore, arrays allocated in this manner exist only until the function that declares them returns. There's no choice in the matter. When the function returns, it's gone. If you need the array to remain in place, and continue to be used, you're out of luck. Do you really believe that large applications, with hundreds of thousands of lines of code, can be implemented simply by writing a single function that allocates all the arrays that it could possibly need, just once, and whose size can never change after the fact?

Comment: ***I can't really understand the difference between Dynamic and static allocation*** This is because you were tricked by an illegal construct (VLAs are not legal in standard c++) that dynamically allocates some memory. When  say some memory I believe most VLA implementations allocate memory on the stack which is only a few MB at most.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I use a pointer rather than the object itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146094/why-should-i-use-a-pointer-rather-than-the-object-itself)

Comment: For the reasons given above I think you will find that pretty much *all* programming languages use pointers. Different languages simply hide them in different ways. What `C++` does is provide an extremely low level way of dealing with pointers directly. Of course in modern `C++` you rarely need to do that unless you are doing something advanced or inherently low level (*someone just needs to tell all the c++ programmers that*).

Comment: OP mentioned "specifically C++", but languages like C# and Java have pointers too.  Although the terminology used by those languages is "references", they're like C++ pointers and not like C++ references.  (Not sure if we're picking on C++ in particular, or if its a broad question about all programming languages.)

Comment: To answer the title of your question:  Pointers contain addresses.  In many systems, pointers are used to access hardware devices at specific addresses.  Pointers can also be used to change the value of variables passed to functions (The preference in C++ is to use references instead).

Comment: I think the real question is why would we need to use `new` if we have VLAs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real point of dynamic allocation is that you control the lifetime of the objects being allocated. Dynamically allocated objects exist until you deallocate them. It's not really anything to do with arrays, although that is often the context in which beginners are first taught about allocation.

Consider these two functions

```
int* bad()
{
    int x = 123;
    return &x;
}

int* good()
{
    int* x = new int(123);
    return x;
}
```

Both functions create an int and return a pointer to that int.

The `bad` function is incorrect because the x variable is destroyed when the function exits, so it returns a pointer to an object which has been destroyed.

The `good` function creates an int dynamically, that object will never be destroyed (unless the program deletes it). So this function is correct.

Incidentally `int size; ... int A[size][size];` is not legal C++. Some compilers allow it, but other compilers would not.

Comment: `int better() { return 123; }` in a lot of cases also for objects. But I admit, this wasn't part of the question.

Comment: @stefaanv Sure I was just trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: i'd rather call it `almost_good` and add a `good` returning a smartpointer

Comment: Dynamic memory is also used for large objects.  Usually, dynamic memory limit is larger than global or automatic memory area.  The global or automatic memory limit is usually larger than the stack area.