# Initialize members at later point without using pointers possible? C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

Say I have a class `A`, that consumes messages of a network. Class `A` has 2 members `b` and `c` of corresponding type `B` and `C`. The members can only be initialized with information, that comes from the network.

Is there a way to initialize the members at a later point, without having the members to be of type `B*` and `C*` (initialize with nullptr and set the wanted value later)?

I feel like in such a scenario the design has a flaw, but I am still asking myself what the best practice would be, as I am kind of sluggish when using pointers after reading [Why should I use a pointer rather than the object itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146094/why-should-i-use-a-pointer-rather-than-the-object-itself) ?

Comment: What about `std::optional<B>` and `std::optional<C>`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I am kind of a beginner and I am not familiar with all features c++ provides. I'll have to look it up, but it might be just what I was asking for.

Comment: what's a problem if it'll be unset?

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин for example when b and c have no default constructor

Comment: so no way you can make it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::optional<T>` is a "nullable" wrapper around a type `T`.  It acts a bit like a pointer in syntax, but there is no dynamic allocation.

```
std::optional<int> bob;
if (bob) // is there anything in the box?
  std::cout << *bob; // print what is in the box.
```

You can do:

```
bob = 7; // Assign 7 to what is in `bob`, or construct with a 7.
bob.emplace(3); // construct the contents of `bob` with the value 3
```

When reading, you can do:

```
std::cout << bob.value_or(-1);
```

which either prints the value in `bob`, or (a `T` constructed from) `-1` if there is nothing there.