# what is stdexp::optional type in C++?

Tags: c++

Just saw the use of `stdexp::optional` in the program(C++). Google search result points me to `std::optional`. It is something not common or it is something that maybe custom defined somewhere in my program?

example:

```
stdexp::optional<std::string> foo;
```

I'm a beginner in C++, so if someone can break down this into simple terms, that would be great

Comment: It's impossible to answer without the actual code but it's likely an alias to `std::experimental`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/experimental/optional - Note that since C++17 `optional` is part of the standard, not experimental anymore.

Comment: @Holt found it in the code `namespace stdexp { using std::experimental::optional; }` Thanks!