# What are the benefits of making a variable permanently a pointer as opposed to only using it as a pointer when needed in C?

Tags: c, oop, pointers, memory-management

I was looking through code as reference to a project I am currently working on. I noticed that instead of having a variable and then only casting a pointer to it temporarily to pass it as a parameter, it was just set to always be a pointer type. (The line where it says `Sprite* createSprite`)

```c
Sprite* createSprite(Sprite* model, int x, int y) {
  Sprite* self = malloc(sizeof(Sprite));
  initSprite(model, self, x, y);
  return self;
}
```

What I assume this is doing, is making the variable permanently a pointer.

Instead of only using the pointer when I would need it:

```c
int a;

someFunction(&a); // We can still use a, and we can also pass it to someFunction as a pointer
```

This code is permanently casting the sprite object to a pointer:

```c
int *a;

someFunction(a); // While we can still use a, it will never be a normal variable.
```

Why would people want to do this and what are the benefits of it?

Comment: Very related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146094 although for a different language.

Comment: @cigien Thank you, sorry that I didn't find this earlier, it is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you will need several sprites in your program.  You *could* do something like

```
Sprite s1;
initSprite(model, &s1, x, y);
Sprite s2;
initSprite(model, &s2, x, y);
Sprite s3;
initSprite(model, &s3, x, y);
```

And then later, if you needed a few more, you *could* do it the same way:

```
Sprite s4;
initSprite(model, &s4, x, y);
Sprite s5;
initSprite(model, &s5, x, y);
```

Sooner or later, though, this gets tedious and unworkable, so you want *dynamic memory allocation*.  That's what the `createSprite` function is doing.  Key within it is that call

```
Sprite* self = malloc(sizeof(Sprite));
```

which dynamically allocates memory for one more sprite.  That way, your program can have as many sprites in it as you want, quite likely a number that won't be known until runtime, once the user has started doing things.  But dynamically allocated memory *always* ends up involving pointers.  It can't use static variable names like your `int a` or my `Sprite s1`, because by definition, there can only ever be a fixed, static number of those (that is, the number you picked the day you wrote the program).

For comparison, it may be instructive to look at three other ways the `createSprite` function could have been written, without using dynamic memory allocation.

```
Sprite* createSprite2(Sprite* model, int x, int y) {
  Sprite self;
  initSprite(model, &self, x, y);
  return &self;
}
```

This creates a local variable of type `Sprite` (not pointer-to-`Sprite`), but it doesn't work, at all.  That local variable disappears when `createSprite2` returns, so the pointer to it is immediately invalid.

```
Sprite* createSprite3(Sprite* model, int x, int y) {
  static Sprite self;
  initSprite(model, &self, x, y);
  return &self;
}
```

Here we make the local `Sprint` variable `static`, so it doesn't disappear when the `createSprite3` returns.  But this doesn't work, either, because now there's really only one `Sprite` object, shared by all the callers who have ever called `createSprite3`, which is almost certainly not what was wanted, and won't work.

But there's one more possibility, which actually *would* work:

```
Sprite createSprite4(Sprite* model, int x, int y) {
  Sprite self;
  initSprite(model, &self, x, y);
  return self;
}
```

Notice that this `createSprite4` does *not* return a pointer -- it returns an actual instance of `Sprite`.  So the caller might look like

```
Sprite s1 = createSprite4(model, x, y);
```

or

```
Sprite manysprites[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    manysprites[i] = createSprite4(model, x, y);
```

As I said, this could work fine, and is a bit of a counterargument to my assertion that "dynamically allocated memory *always* ends up involving pointers".  (Technically, though, there's still no dynamically allocated memory here, as we can see from the source code that there are exactly 1, or 10, Sprites allocated.)

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth response. If it doesn't take too much time, could you please give me an example of how I could use the pointer (original) snippet to dynamically allocate to have multiple sprites like you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

In your first example

```
 int a;
 someFunction(&a);
```

'a' exists on the stack , so it has a name you can use and take the address or etc.

The sprite example

```
Sprite* createSprite(Sprite* model, int x, int y) {
  Sprite* self = malloc(sizeof(Sprite));
  initSprite(model, self, x, y);
  return self;
}
```

is almost certainly dynamically allocating its data on the heap. The only way you can refer to dynamically allocated memory is via a pointer

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Which method do you think is better/more appropriate, and why?

Answer (score 0):

`createSprite` returns a pointer to `self`; if it was like this (which is what I guess you expected to also work):

```
Sprite* createSprite(Sprite* model, int x, int y) {
  Sprite self;
  initSprite(model, &self, x, y);
  return &self;
}
```

the memory allocated to `self` would be invalid by the time the function execution ended; trying to access it through the returned pointer would most likely result in a segfault.