# scoped_ptr and the c++ standard library

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, raii, std, scoped-ptr

is there a reason why scoped_ptr isn't part of the standard library? are there any plans about it in the future? Some cases I prefer to use scoped_ptr over unique_ptr since it is non-movable unlike the later.

Comment: You want the C++ standard library to provide you with a deliberately crippled class template? Not likely.

Comment: Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5294005/481267

Comment: For the same reason any feature (red-black-green trees, trinary trees, hash chairs, native quaternian data type, long long long long long int data type, binary coded decimal) isn't part of the standard. Either it wasn't put forward or it was put forward and delayed/dropped.