# Smart pointer that does transfer of ownership and is not shared when C++11 is not an option

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Currently I am solving my problem with `boost::shared_ptr` but the semantics is not quite right, since I am "transplanting" members from one object to another. I was looking through [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026197/what-c-smart-pointer-implementations-are-available) but it didn't yield too much. Same goes for my brief google searches.

Essentially I am looking for a `unique_ptr` implementation that works with my gcc4.2 (Hence the restriction to not use C++11)

Comment: strongly suggest this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569775/smart-pointers-boost-explained

Comment: The latest boost (1.48) has a Boost.Move library that mimics move semantics in C++03. I guess that a `unique_ptr` could be implemented on top of it (and maybe it was, I haven't looked at it much).

Comment: @sehe Saw it, the pointers are either shared or can't transfer the ownership at all (scoped)

Comment: ANY ownership pointer will not work with the STL library. That is why everyone tells you to stay away from auto_ptr. There are no serious bugs; ownership pointers will inherently not work with the STL library.

Comment: Ok, I think so far I can live with not being STL compatible. The pointer is well hidden in one class and never exposed to anyone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could stick with `std::auto_ptr` until Boost implements `unique_ptr` on top of the new [`Boost Move` library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/move.html) (C++03 compatible).

See this mailing list traffic d.d. November 10th 2011: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/smart-ptr-Inclusion-of-unique-ptr-td4021667.html

**Edit** And Boost Interprocess has a `uniqe_ptr<>` class template floating around:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/unique_ptr.html

Comment: found something in the interprocess boost libs

Comment: +1 for `auto_ptr` which, despite all the haterade spewed about it, is just perfect for some scenarios.\

Comment: Wow! Boost.Move seems a really useful library in C++03.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what exactly you want, you might consider using `boost::scoped_ptr`. It is very similar to `std::unique_ptr`, but it cannot be moved (because C++03 doesn't know about move-semantics). It can, however be swapped. So, when you want to transfer ownership, just do this:

```
boost::scoped_ptr<T> dummy;
dummy.swap(my_ptr);
// now you have basically transferred ownership from my_ptr to dummy
```

Comment: That seems to be the first solution to try, since I am already using boost.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::auto_ptr<..>, it has exactly what you need.

Comment: Everyone is telling me to stay away from `auto_ptr`.

Comment: Be aware that using auto_ptr in STL containers may cause undefined behavior, depending on what you are doing.  (That is partly why auto_ptr is being replaced by unique_ptr.)  See http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=400

Comment: `auto_ptr` is deprecated in current C++ standard. Also in C++03 using it wasn't good practice.

Comment: What are their reasons? I'm interested as I'm using auto_ptr as a placeholder for unique_ptr functionality as well.

Comment: @Abyx, after saying something isn't good practice, it would be helpful and educational to explain why.

Answer (score 1):

[llvm::OwningPtr](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/OwningPtr_8h_source.html) - it has `take` method to take ownership.

Answer (score 0):

boost::shared_ptr with custom deleter.

This is something I used in unit test to simulate Corba _var class behaviour.

```
struct CondDel {
  bool doDel;
  CondDel() : doDel(true) {
  }
  template<typename T>
  void operator()(T* p) {
    if (doDel)
      delete p;
  }
};
class MyCorbaObj_var : public boost::shared_ptr<_objref_MyCorbaObj> {
public:
  MyCorbaObj_var(_objref_MyCorbaObj* p) : boost::shared_ptr<_objref_MyCorbaObj>(p, CondDel()) {
  }
  _objref_MyCorbaObj* _retn() {
    CondDel* cd = (CondDel*)_internal_get_deleter(typeid(CondDel));
    cd->doDel = false;
    return get();
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want copying objects of your class to make new copies of the pointed-to items, then no kind of pointer (auto_ptr, shared_ptr or naked pointer) will do what you want without some extra work on your part.  You will need to manage the copying yourself.  Be sure you implement a copy constructor and assignment operator so that they clone the pointed-to items and store the new pointers in the destination object.  If you do this, auto_ptr and shared_ptr will both work just fine for you.

Comment: This is not what is being asked; anyway, a "pointer" that copies the pointed-to object is not a pointer any more, it's a **container**.