# smart pointers: shared ownership: non-intrusive/intrusive strategy

Tags: terminology, smart-pointers

We know that shared ownership has two underlying strategies:

- non-intrusive and
- intrusive

Please help me to understand what do these strategies mean?
What are implementation details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-intrusive is when the smart pointer object provides reference counting.
Ex.: `std::shared_ptr`, `boost::shared_ptr`

Intrusive is when the smart pointer relies on stored object embedded reference counting (i.e. stored object is responsible for reference counting).
Ex.: `boost::intrusive_ptr`

Note: intrusive pointer needs the "glue" code to increment and decrement reference counter inside the stored object. In boost library you must provide 2 functions to the `intrusive_ptr` object to perform reference counter increment and decrement.

---

[smart pointers (boost) explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569775/smart-pointers-boost-explained)
There is no direct answer on my question here but is very helpful as a quick overview of smart pointers semantics.