# Dealing with memory leaks in class new and delete operators C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I enjoy using the operators `new` and `delete` in C++ a lot but often have a problem calling `delete` later on in the program's code.

For example, in the following code:

```
class Foo {
public:
    string *ace;
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
};
Foo::Foo() {
    ace = new string;
}
Foo::~Foo() {
    delete ace;
}
void UI::ButtonPressed() { //Happens when an event is triggered
    Foo *foo = new Foo;
    ui->label = ace; //Set some text on the GUI
    delete foo; //Calls the destructor, deleting "ace" and removing it from the GUI window
}
```

I can declare a `new` string but when I `delete` it, it removes the value from the GUI form because that string has now been deleted.

Is there a way for me to delete this allocated string somehow later on?

I don't want to declare it as a global variable and then `delete` it on the last line of the program's source code. I could just never call `delete` but from what I have been taught that's bad and results in memory leaks.

Comment: A `std::string` can vary, so in your example you could declare `std::string ace;` and you probably should learn more about smart pointers, etc. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer

Comment: Do you happen to know if smart pointers work with non-standard C++ data types like `QString`(QT) and others?

Comment: Qt also have some kind of smart pointers, and yes, `std::smart_ptr` et al. should work with Qt...

Comment: @user99545: One of the reasons why `std::string` exists is so you don't have to worry about `new`ing and `delete`ing the character array. Just make it a class member and it'll take care of itself.

Comment: ¤ As @Insilico says, `std::string` is one solution. `std::string` takes the decision out of your hands about whether to *copy* or *share* the data: you don't know what it does, and you don't need to know (it's functionally as if it copied). To implement copying yourself, you need to read up on the "rule of three" for proper destruction. To implement sharing yourself, use a `std::shared_ptr`. Unfortunately there is no copying smart pointer in the standard library, not even in Boost I think. Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about the [RAII pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). It is one of the most important concepts to know for a C++ programmer.

The basic idea is that the lifetime of a resource (a new'ed object, an HTTP connection, etc.) is tied to the lifetime of an object. This is necessary in order to write exception safe code.

In your case, the UI widget would make a copy of the object and free it in its own destructor. The calling code could then free its copy right away (in another destructor).

Comment: Thanks for teaching me the RAII pattern, after some quick research all my questions have been answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `std::string` for both `ace` and `ui->label` then you don't have to worry about the memory for `foo->ace` being `delete`d once the `foo` object goes out of scope.

A copy of the Right-Hand  argument is made available to `ui->label` on an `=` (assignment operation). You can read more about it on the C++ [`std::string` reference page for `string::operator=`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator=/).

Also, such problems can be avoided in full by using smart pointers, such as the ones provided by the [boost library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm). Read [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569775/smart-pointers-boost-explained) on stackoverflow on this subject to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a lot to say of your code. Some things have already been said, e.g. that you should make string a normal member so the allocation/deallcoation issue goes away completely (that's a general rule for C++ programs: If you don't absolutely *have to* use dynamic allocation, then don't, period). Also, using an appropriate smart pointer would do the memory management for you (also a general rule in C++: Don't manage the dynamic allocations yourself unless you really have to).

However let's pretend that you have to use dynamic allocation, and you have to use raw pointers and direct `new` and `delete` here. Then another important rule comes in (which actually isn't a C++ specific rule, but a general OO rule): Don't make the member public. Make it a private member, and offer a public member function for setting it. That public member function then can properly delete the old object before assigning the pointer to the new one. Note that as soon as you assigned the pointer, unless you've stored the old value elsewhere, the old value is lost forever, and if the object has not been deleted up to then, you can't delete it later.

You also want to consider whether it is really a good idea to take ownership of an object passed to you by pointer (and assigning to a pointer member which has a delete in the destructor *is* a ― not very obvious ― way to pass ownership). This complicates the object lifetime management because you have to remember whether you passed a certain object to an ownership-claiming object (this is not an issue if you have a strict policy of *always* passing to ownership-claiming objects, though). As usual, smart pointers may help here; however you may consider whether it is a better option to make a copy of the passed object (for `std::string` it definitely is, but then, here it's better to have a direct member anyway, as mentioned above).

So here's a full list of rules, where earlier rules take precedence to later unless there's a good reason not to use it:

1. Don't use dynamical allocation.
2. Manage your dynamical allocation with smart pointers.
3. Use `new` only in constructors and `delete` only in the corresponding destructor.
4. Always have the `new` and `delete` for a specific pointer in member functions of the same class. (Actually the previous rule is a special case of this one, but a special case which should be preferred to the general one.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more idiomatic C++ program:

```
class Foo {
public:
    std::string ace;

    Foo() : ace() {
      // nothing to do here. ace knows how to create itself…
    }

    // and copy itself…
    Foo(const Foo& other) : ace(other.ace) {}

     // and clean up after itself…
    ~Foo() {
    }

    // and copy/assign itself…
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& other) {
      this->ace = other.ace;
      return *this;
    }
};


void UI::ButtonPressed() {
  // `new` is not needed here, either!
  Foo foo;
  ui->label = foo.ace; //Set some text on the GUI
  // `delete` is not needed here
}
```

If you *really* need to call `new`, always use an appropriate smart pointer -- Writing `delete` is banished from modern C++ ;)