# Should I use shared_ptr or unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have a question about [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). I know there are loads of questions about when to use which one, but I'm still not sure if I understand it correctly. I read somewhere that the default choice for smart pointer should be `std::unique_ptr`, but as I understand it, for my needs I should rather use `std::shared_ptr`. For example, I have:

```
class B;
class A
{
private:
   B* b;
public:
   B* getB();
};

A::getB()
{
   return b;
}
```

So basically class `A` owns pointer to object of type `B` and there's a method which returns this pointer. If I create getter, I assume that some other class can access this pointer and therefore it should be `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`. Am I right, or I don't get it yet?

Comment: If you need to share a pointer, use `std::shared_ptr`. If you _don't_ need to share a pointer, use `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876751/differences-between-unique-ptr-and-shared-ptr and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569775/smart-pointers-boost-explained

Comment: @JoachimPileborg still if he returns a bare pointer like he does there is no sense in using a `shared_ptr`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Short answer: depends.

It depends on if the pointer returned by `getB` may be stored/used somewhere while the owning A has gone out of scope. The difference is about *ownership* not about how many pointers you do have.

- If the A still exists when you use the result of `getB` , you can store a `unique_ptr` and return a plain pointer (or a reference if `getB` can never return `nullptr`). That expresses "A owns B, and no-one else does".
- If the A might go out of scope while you are using/holding the result of `getB`, but the B should go out of scope together with (or shortly after) the A, store a `shared_ptr` and return a `weak_ptr`.
- If possibly many objects, including the callers of `getB`, may hold on to the B and there is no clear single owner, store and return `shared_ptr`s.

Answer (score 7):

Let's assume for the sake of example that a pointer is really needed and just `B b;` doesn't cut it (maybe B is polymorphic, for example).

#### Scenario alpha

So, A is *the* owner of a B.

```
private:
   std::unique_ptr<B> b;
```

And `getB` provides a view of that B.

```
public:
   B& getB();


B& A::getB()
{
   return *b;
}
```

#### Scenario beta

A is *one of* the owners of a B.

```
private:
   std::shared_ptr<B> b;
```

And A can give ownership of that B to others.

```
public:
   std::shared_ptr<B> getB();


std::shared_ptr<B> A::getB()
{
   return b;
}
```

Comment: Scenario alpha does not account for the possibility that b is NULL. It depends on that possibility and on the usage of the returned ptr/ref, if `getB` should return a reference, a plain pointer or a `weak_ptr`, the latter of course demands a stored `shared_ptr`

Answer (score 2):

You return a bare pointer, not a `shared_ptr`, so making the pointer shared will solve nothing. Either return a `shared_ptr`, or use a `unique_ptr`. Try to think of how can possible `shared_ptr` be implemented and I believe this should make my point clear.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are right. 
If you would only story the `B` pointer as private member in `A`, I think I would use an `std::unqiue_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough information in the question.

Smart pointers capture and implement ownership semantics. If the `A` object owns the `B` object, so destroying the `A` should destroy the `B`, then use `unique_ptr`. But `unique_ptr` doesn't make a good return type here. It would only be the member and you would still return a bare pointer.

If getting the `B` means the client can continue using the `B` indefinitely, then use `shared_ptr`, because that would be shared ownership.