# smart pointer in the std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, smart-pointers, assign, auto-ptr

I've defined a class `myClass`,one of its data members is

```
std::map<int,data*> dataMap
```

data is defined as

```
struct data
{
    int d1;
    int d2;
    std::string d3;
}
```

Inserting of data to the dataMap is done as follows :`dataMap[key] = new data;`
the following assignment causes a problem:

```
myClass a1,a2;
//init a1;
a2 = a1;
```

I want to use auto_ptr for data instead of data*.how do i do that?-
since there are a problem with destructing "bad pointers for data of a1" after a2 is destructed.`std::map<int,std::auto_ptr<data> >` is problematic to compile

**Upd** As you advised I use std::shared_ptr but it still causes a problems :
in `VS10`

```
error C2440: 'delete' : cannot convert from 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>' to 'void *'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=data
1>          ]
```

Can you write sample code pointing the correct way to use shared_ptr

Comment: Are you using C++03 or C++11?

Comment: Don't use `auto_ptr`, if you have access to c++11, use either `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, else fall back to using `boost::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this error:
 `error C2440: 'delete' : cannot convert from 'std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>' to 'void *'`
You don't need to delete an instant of shared_ptr. The shared_ptr would hold the resource (the `new data`) with a reference counter, and delete it automatically when the reference counter is 0, meaning that the resource was not used at all. See the [manual of shared_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) for detail

Answer (score 4):

Using `auto_ptr` is a bad idea (it is deprecated) in general and even worse [when combined with standard containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111478/why-is-it-wrong-to-use-stdauto-ptr-with-standard-containers).

Prefer the better designed `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` ([depending on your situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569775/smart-pointers-boost-explained)) and your code will work with one exception: You need to construct the correct smart pointer type when trying to insert it into the container, as the smart pointers are not implicitly constructible from raw pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`std::auto_ptr` is not safe to be used in containers, that why it's been deprecated. Use `std::shared_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr` if available.

You could also use `std::unique_ptr` if appropriate and available, but it is a bit trickier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `std::unique_ptr` in C++11 if you have a unique ownership (ie, the object will never be shared and only the creator can destruct it again) or you can use `std::shared_ptr` if you will have shared ownership.

If you're using C++03 you can use `boost::shared_ptr` or `boost::unique_ptr` instead.