# C++ Add derived object of abstract class into another class without dangling pointers?

Tags: c++, containers, abstract-class, dangling-pointer

I have a simple container class that points to an abstract class and I have functions to get/set the pointer in the container class. More concretely, the class looks like this:

```
class Container
{
    Abstract* thing;
public:
    void set(Abstract &obj)
    {
        thing = &obj; //danger of dangling pointer
    }

    Abstract* get()
    {
        return thing;
    }
};
```

`Abstract` is an abstract class. As can be seen already, there's a danger of a dangling pointer. I know that I could make a copy of the object (new) and then point to it. But I can't create an instance of an abstract class. What solutions to this are there?

---

The following are just more information:

**Class definitions**

```
class Abstract
{
public:
    virtual void something() = 0;
};

class Base : public Abstract
{
    int a;
public:
    Base() {}
    Base(int a) : a(a){}
    virtual void something()
    {
        cout << "Base" << endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    int b;
public:
    Derived() {}
    Derived(int a, int b) : Base(a), b(b){}
    virtual void something()
    {
        cout << "Derived" << endl;
    }
};
```

**Simple tests**

```
void setBase(Container &toSet)
{
    Base base(15);
    toSet.set(base);
}

void setDerived(Container &toSet)
{
    Derived derived(10, 30);
    toSet.set(derived);
}

int main()
{
    Container co;

    Base base(15);
    Derived derived(10, 30);

    Base *basePtr;
    Derived *derivedPtr;

    //This is fine
    co.set(base);
    basePtr = static_cast<Base *>(co.get());
    basePtr->something();

    //This is fine
    co.set(derived);
    derivedPtr = static_cast<Derived *>(co.get());
    derivedPtr->something();

    //Reset
    basePtr = nullptr;
    derivedPtr = nullptr;

    //Dangling pointer!
    setBase(co);
    basePtr = static_cast<Base *>(co.get());
    basePtr->something();

    //Dangling pointer!
    setDerived(co);
    derivedPtr = static_cast<Derived *>(co.get());
    derivedPtr->something();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Care to share the reason of the downvote?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one)

Comment: @silentwf The downvote reasons are shared at the tooltip when you're hovering the DV button with the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is to define your memory ownership concretely.

`Container::set` accepts an instance of `Abstract` by reference, which usually does not imply an ownership transfer:

```
 void set(Abstract &obj){...} // Caller retains ownership of obj, but now we have a weak reference to it
```

Then the onus of deletion is not on you.

`Container::get` returns a **pointer** which implies ownership, indicating that someone who calls `set` should not invalidate the passed object.

```
Abstract* get(){...}
```

This could be problematic, as you've stated.

You have a few options

- Encode these memory ownership semantics within `Container` with proper documentation ([Code by contract](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract))
- Use a smart pointer like `std::shared_ptr`

In the former case, whether it works or not depends on the user reading and understanding your API, and then behaving nicely with it. In the latter case, the pointer object owns itself, and will delete the allocated memory when the last instance goes out of scope.

```
 void set(std::shared_ptr<Abstract> obj){...} 
// now Container participates in the lifetime of obj, 
// and it's harder to nullify the underlying object 
// (you'd have to be intentionally misbehaving)
```

Comment: Because I hate stupidity like `delete myContainer.get();` can I talk you into `Abstract& get(){...}`?

Comment: @user4581301: Why would you be deleting `myContainer.get()`? It will delete itself, and calling `delete` manually will result in a segmentation fault.

Comment: Yup. It's careless, but you can do it. The problem will likely not be with blatant and immediate error, but mis-handling what looks like a raw pointer a few dozen lines of code later. The reference ramps up the difficulty of accidentally screwing up into the intentionally misbehaving category.

Comment: @AndyG Curious how the first half solves the problem though? Assuming that there's no "get" function, then I'd still have to use smart pointers no?

Comment: You don't need to use smart pointers if the user is well-behaved. Design by contract assume preconditions and postconditions are met. Therefore, a precondition on `get` is that the data added in the previous `set` has not been invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about the object being deallocated elsewhere resulting in a dangling pointer, you could use boost smart pointers.

Boost smart pointers would provide you the service of book keeping and help to avoid such a case.

Some information can be found here : 
[smart pointers (boost) explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569775/smart-pointers-boost-explained)

Answer (score 1):

This is what `std::unique_ptr` is for:

```
class Container
{
    std::unique_ptr<Abstract> thing;
public:
    void set(std::unique_ptr<Abstract> obj)
    {
        thing = obj;
    }

    Abstract* get()
    {
        return thing.get();
    }
};
```

Now the `Abstract` object is "owned" by `Container` and will be cleaned up automatically when the `Conatiner` is destroyed.

If you want a pointer that might live longer, or might be shared between mulitple containers, use `std::shared_ptr` instead.