# pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> to pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr (Covert poincloud to ptr)

Tags: pointers, shared-ptr, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, outliers

I am using PCL 1.3. Is there any function to convert pointcloud to pointcloud::ptr. I am new at PCL libraries. I have a ROS node subscribing to sensor_msgs/PoinCloud2 topic then I am converting it into pcl::Poincloud and now I want to do pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval. The outlier removal function takes in the pointers, not the Poincloud itself(That's what I understood). So for that purpose I would like to know the solution of how to convert between them?

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> point_cloud
pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(cloud_filtered, point_cloud);


pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud(point_cloud, point_cloud, nan_idx);

pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval<pcl::PointXYZ> sor;
sor.setInputCloud (point_cloud);
sor.setMeanK (50);
sor.setStddevMulThresh (1.0);
sor.filter (*point_cloud);
```

error: **no matching function** for call to ‘pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemovalpcl::PointXYZ::setInputCloud(**pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ**&)’

note: **candidate**: void pcl::PCLBase::setInputCloud(**const PointCloudConstPtr&**) [with PointT = pcl::PointXYZ; pcl::PCLBase::PointCloudConstPtr = boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ >]

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr` is a [shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569775/smart-pointers-boost-explained) - so, simply speaking, it is a wrapper around a **pointer** that manages it's lifetime (in our case a wrapper around a pointer to `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>`).

You instatiate it by passing a pointer, such as the one that comes from a `new`:
`pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr point_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud< pcl::PointXYZ>);`

Since `pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2` expects a `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>`, you need [dereferencing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean):
`pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(cloud_filtered, *point_cloud);`

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution worked. Thank you for a nice and detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting also is that with ros_pcl you can directly have a subscriber that
directly subscribes to:

`const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr& message`

when sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 messages are published on the subscribed topic this will work out of the box and you do not have to call:

`pcl::fromPCLPointCloud2(cloud_filtered, point_cloud);`